# Custom Loop Event Page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, events

I need to create a loop in an event page with pagination of 10 posts per page.
The way I want to do it is a little bit complicated.

For example, with current date May 1, 2015:

> January 1, 2015 - March 1, 2015 - June 1, 2015 - September 1, 2015

I want to list all my events like that: (First: Future events ordered by ASC) - (After: Past events ordered by DESC)

So the final result of the loop:

> June 1, 2015 - September 1, 2015 / - / March 1, 2015 - January 1, 2015

```
$current_date = current_time( 'timestamp', true );
$page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type'      => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby'        => '_start_eventtimestamp',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'page'           => $page,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'       => '_start_eventtimestamp',
            'value'     => $current_date,
            'compare'   => '>'
        ),
    )
) );
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    // THE LOOP
endwhile; endif:
```

This code is for future events ordered by ASC, without past events. I can create another loop to get past events easily but I will get only two loops separately and it's not the result I want. And I will not get the pagination.

Comment: You should use sql query to accomplish this. The default wordpress way will need a lot more queries and will be very complicated. The downside of using custom sql query is that you can't use the loop and create the pagination yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's complicated so I prefer make an alternative for the organisation of my website. I will create a page futur events and a page past events.